# I need to use System.Security.Cryptography in windows phone app

Tags: c#, .net, dll, windows-phone-8, sha

I'm trying to cast a string in a SHA-1 string. It's for a password.

I can't make a using System.Security.Cryptography in my class. I don't know what DLL I need.

Could you help me please ?

The class is in a portable library.

I'm not really good in english, sorry !

Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate SHA1 Hash in Portable Class LIbrary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254369/generate-sha1-hash-in-portable-class-library)

Answer (score 0):

Cryptography functionality is platform specific and cannot be used in a portable class library.

Instead, you'll need to abstract that into libraries that were custom built for each platform. In your case, you'll need to write the Cryptography related code in an assembly specifically targeting Windows Phone. You cannot put the code in a portable class library.

For some guidance as to how to abstract the code, [here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#abstraction) an idea on MSDN.