# How do you hash a string in a PCL project?

Tags: xamarin

We've tried using this library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm(v=vs.110).aspx

And this code:

```
public static byte[] GetHash(string inputString)
{
    HashAlgorithm algorithm = SHA1.Create();  // SHA1.Create()
    return algorithm.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString));
}

public static string GetHashString(string inputString)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in GetHash(inputString))
        sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

But the library doesn't seem to be available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate SHA1 Hash in Portable Class Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254369/generate-sha1-hash-in-portable-class-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case certain API is not available in PCL, you would normally create an interface of and inject it in the constructor.

In your example, it would be something like this

**PCL library project**

```
public interface IHashService 
{
     byte[] ComputeHash(byte[] data)
}
```

**Platform specific project**

```
public class Sha1HashService : IHashService 
{
    public ComputeHash(byte[] data) 
    {
         using(var algorithm = SHA1.Create())
         {
              var result = algorithm.ComputeHash(data);
              return result;
         }
    }  
}
```

It is good practice not to use static methods and use a dependency injection whenever possible.
Also you probably want your interface to be more generic (takes bytes as an argument) rather than a string, for the very same reason (dependency on the Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes).